# Obtener una secuencia para un subconjunto de la consulta

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
| cod |producto|  ingrediente|
|-----|--------|-------------|
|3456 |Galletas|       harina|
|3456 |Galletas|       azúcar|
|3456 |Galletas|        huevo|
|12345|cocacola|      cafeína|
|12345|cocacola|ácido cítrico|
```

¿Cómo podría hacer obtener una secuencia para un subconjunto de la consulta, utilizando como agrupación el código de barras(cod)?

La **salida** esperada sería:

```
| cod |producto|  ingrediente| ingrediente_numero|
|-----|--------|-------------|-------------------|
|3456 |Galletas|       harina|                  1|       
|3456 |Galletas|       azúcar|                  2|
|3456 |Galletas|        huevo|                  3|
|12345|cocacola|      cafeína|                  1|
|12345|cocacola|ácido cítrico|                  2|
```

Comment: Bienvenido! No se recomienda utilizar imágenes con el fin que le estás dando. Deberías escribir lo que aparece en la imagen en tu pregunta. Si no es posible que tu pregunta acabé cerrada. Deberías de hacer el recorrido de bienvenida para saber cómo funciona el sitio. Independiente de esto, deberías aportar más información, cómo por ejemplo el motor de bbdd que estás usando. Por lo que respecta a tu duda, ¿Has oído hablar de las funciones ventana?

Comment: Lo que pides, en PostgreSQL sería algo como: `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_barras ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) num_ingredientes FROM miTabla`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Tu comentario me ayudo mucho, gracias :)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo podes elaborar una respuesta con lo que decis?

Comment: @gbianchi En cuanto llegue a casa, lo pruebo y posteo. Saludos! :)

Comment: y de paso Augusto Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! [type here]

Comment: @AugustoA, sugiero añadir a tu pregunta la etiqueta del motor de base de datos que utilizas, pues la respuesta tiende a ser distinta para distintos motores. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a basar en Postgres, ya que no se especifica, pero supongo que en otros gestores de BBDD funcionaría o habría funcionalidades similares.

Podrías usar una función ventana ([Documentación de Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html)).

Traduciendo de la documentación:

> Una función ventana hace cálcular sobre un conjunto de filas de la tabla que están relacionadas de alguna manera con la fila actual. Es comparable al tipo de cálculo que puede ser hecho con una función de agregación. Pero al contrario que las típicas funciones de agragación, el uso de una función ventana no causa que las filas se agrupen en una única fila de salida — las filas conservan sus identidades.

Tu consulta podría usar la función [**ROW_NUMBER**](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/), que obtiene el número de fila actual:

```
ROW_NUMBER()
```

Sobre los subconjuntos agrupados por la columna `cod`:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY cod) AS num_ingrediente
```

De esta forma obtendremos que numere secuencialmente sobre cada subconjunto.

La consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
    cod, 
    producto, 
    ingrediente,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cod) AS num_ingrediente
FROM table;
```

---

**Consulta**

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.cod) AS num_ingrediente
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (3456, 'Galletas', 'harina'),
    (3456, 'Galletas', 'azúcar'),
    (3456, 'Galletas', 'huevo'),
    (12345, 'cocacola', 'cafeina'),
    (12345, 'cocacola', 'acido citrico')) AS t(cod, producto, ingrediente)
)x;
```

```
| cod   | producto | ingrediente   | num_ingrediente |
| ----- | -------- | ------------- | --------------- |
| 3456  | Galletas | harina        | 1               |
| 3456  | Galletas | azúcar        | 2               |
| 3456  | Galletas | huevo         | 3               |
| 12345 | cocacola | cafeina       | 1               |
| 12345 | cocacola | acido citrico | 2               |
```

---

[Ver en DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gwjig5NTPRQQ2hNYG59j54/0)